# how to expand the UITextview when user clicks on "more " Button in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

There are applications with a UITextview that shows a given amount of lines and when the user clicks more it expands and shows the rest,how to add more and less button.Please give me any idea. i am new to the programming.I know how to write the code of UITextview.But i dont know how to write the code of More or less button for UITextview.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? How would you change the height of any view in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Check UItextView size base on text and Font:

```
// return the size for UITextView for both IOS7 and IOS6
-(CGSize) getSizeWithMaxLabelSize:(CGSize) maxLabelSize forTextViewWithText:(NSString *) text
{
CGSize expectedLabelSize;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = maxLabelSize;
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"6.2")) {
    NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:EPCommentViewFontSize] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
    CGRect rect =[text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:stringAttributes context:nil];
    expectedLabelSize = rect.size;
    expectedLabelSize.height = ceilf(expectedLabelSize.height);
    expectedLabelSize.width  = ceilf(expectedLabelSize.width);
} else {
    expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:EPCommentViewFontSize] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}
  return expectedLabelSize;
}
```

2.Change `UITextView` `frame.size.height`

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = [self getSizeWithMaxLabelSize:CGSizeMake(_textView.frame.size.height, NSIntegerMax) forTextViewWithText:_textView.text].height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

3.Change subviews layout

```
// this will work only if you textview is on the top of other views. 
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) 
            subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, _textView.frame.size.height);
}];
```

Should be it.

Comment: thanks for your response.But i cant understand properly.Please can you explain briefly or give me any sample code. because i am new to the programming.Thank you so much brother.

Comment: What you did not understand exactly ? I already gave you sample code.