# UITextView - Truncate text on iOS 6 showing ellipsis (using Autolayout)

Tags: ios, uitextview, autolayout

I have a `UITextView` that displays text longer than what can be fit into the textview's frame. I want the text to be truncated by showing **ellipsis** on iOS 6.

On **iOS 7** I am able to achieve this by using the following code

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0;
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

On **iOS 6** I am able to truncate the text but it doesn't display the ellipsis.

Problem is on **iOS6** the property `textContainer` is not available

**Pls Note:**

- I am using AutoLayout and hence I wouldn't know the frame size when the text is being set. The frame size gets set much later.

**Question**

On iOS 6 how would I be able to show the ellipsis ?

Comment: I see that you are truncating the textView

Comment: I have edited the question to be be more specific about my problem. The problem is Ellipsis is not shown in iOS 6.

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing on iOS 6? Screenshot, maybe?

Comment: Yes i know but you are using NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail which will do that . Change the style to something like wordwrap

Comment: @StevenFisher I have edited the question again, On iOS6 the text gets truncated but ellipsis is not shown.

Comment: @meda on iOS6, `textContainer` is not available, it is available in iOS 7

Comment: This is much much easier if you are willing to draw the text yourself or use UILabel (not use UITextView). Is that a possibility in your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, @matt helped me find my solution.

I suppose the best fit for my problem is using a UILabel instead.

The only problem I was facing with UILabel and Autolayout was that when the text is just one line, the text was center aligned vertically and it looked odd.

**Solution (Autolayout and UILabel)**

1. Use UILabel
2. Set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to desired value. **This is what I was really missing**
3. Set the height constraint to be **less than or equal** to desired value
4. Use `sizeToFit` after setting the text and after orientation change

So if the height returned by sizeToFit is a smaller height than the max height, then that size would be taken otherwise, max height set in step 3 would be taken

This works on both iOS 6 and iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing this in iOS 6. But you can try the following

```
int maximumCharacters = 200;
if([str length] > maximumCharacters) {
    str = [str substringToIndex:maxCharacters];
}
```

Adding the ellipsis: [This post may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416846/how-to-expand-the-uitextview-when-user-clicks-on-more-button-in-ios)